# new line issue with f.write

Tags: python, txt

I'm trying to use the `f.write` keyword, I want each thing I write to be in a new line so I did this:

```
f.write('',message_variable_from_previous_input,'\n')
```

However, after I ran this it threw back an error saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User1\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\folder_namr\file_name.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write('',msg,'\n')
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Does anybody know haw to fix this?

Comment: You have to give only one string

Comment: modify `f.write('',message_variable_from_previous_input,'\n')` to pass a single string - currently you're passing 3

Comment: `.write()` doesn't take multiple parameters - perhaps you're thinking of how `print()` works, but that's a feature specific to that function.  Either concatenate the three items with `+`, or use three separate `.write()`s.

Comment: You could form 1 string from the 3 for example ```f'{message_variable_from_previous_input}\n'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write` method takes exactly one argument

so you should write like this:

```
f.write(f"{message_variable_from_previous_input}\n")
```

or:

```
f.write(str(message_variable_from_previous_input) + "\n")
```